# Pass a Parameter object (PSCredential) inside a ScriptBlock programmatically in C#

Tags: c#, powershell, hpc

I am trying to run an HPC cmdlet programmatically to change HPC install credential on a remote computer. If run the cmdlet locally, it's pretty straightforward:

```
Runspace rs = GetPowerShellRunspace();
rs.Open();

Pipeline pipeline = rs.CreatePipeline();
PSCredential credential = new PSCredential(domainAccount, newPassword);
Command cmd = new Command("Set-HpcClusterProperty");
cmd.Parameters.Add("InstallCredential", credential);

pipeline.Commands.Add(cmd);

Collection<PSObject> ret = pipeline.Invoke();
```

However, if I want to do the same thing with remote PowerShell, I need to run Invoke-Command and pass in the credential to the ScriptBlock inside the Command. How can I do that? It might look something like this, except I need to pass in the credential as an object binded to the InstallCredential parameter inside the ScriptBlock instead of a string:

```
Pipeline pipeline = rs.CreatePipeline();
PSCredential credential = new PSCredential(domainAccount, newPassword);

pipeline.Commands.AddScript(string.Format(
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    "Invoke-Command -ComputerName {0} -ScriptBlock {{ Set-HpcClusterProperty -InstallCredential {1} }}",
    nodeName,
    credential));

Collection<PSObject> ret = pipeline.Invoke();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would continue to use AddCommand for `Invoke-Command` (instead of AddScript).  Add the parameters for Invoke-Command and when you get to `Scriptblock` parameter, make sure the scriptblock defines a param() block e.g.:

```
{param($cred) Set-HpcClusterProperty -InstallCredential $cred}
```

Then add the `ArgumentList` parameter to the `Invoke-Command` command and set the value to the credential you have created.

Answer (score 9):

```
powershell.AddCommand("Set-Variable");
powershell.AddParameter("Name", "cred");
powershell.AddParameter("Value", Credential);

powershell.AddScript(@"$s = New-PSSession -ComputerName '" + serverName + "' -Credential $cred");
powershell.AddScript(@"$a = Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {" + cmdlet + "}");
powershell.AddScript(@"Remove-PSSession -Session $s");
powershell.AddScript(@"echo $a");
```

Where Credential is the c# PSCredential object

I use this, maybe it can help you.