# How to Pass PSCredential object from C# code to Powershell Function

Tags: c#, powershell

I have a PSCredential Object in C# and want to pass it as parameter for this PowerShell Script

This is the PSCredential Object

```
    PSCredential Credential = new PSCredential ( "bla" , blasecurestring)
```

This is the Script I want to run in C#

```
powershell.AddScript("$s = New-PSSession -ComputerName '" + serverName + "' -Credential " + Credential);
```

I couldn't understand the solution which is offered here [Pass a Parameter object (PSCredential) inside a ScriptBlock programmatically in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961192/pass-a-parameter-object-pscredential-inside-a-scriptblock-programmatically-in)

EDIT:
This thing is working

```
powershell.AddCommand("New-PSSession").AddParameter("ComputerName", serverName).AddParameter("Credential", Credential);
```

But how can I save the Session Info in a variable? I need them for the following commands:

```
powershell.AddScript(@"Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {" + cmdlet + "}");
```

Comment: Maybe it is possible to go without pipelines

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the solution now. It's so easy when you know what you do...

```
powershell.AddCommand("Set-Variable");
powershell.AddParameter("Name", "cred");
powershell.AddParameter("Value", Credential);

powershell.AddScript(@"$s = New-PSSession -ComputerName '" + serverName + "' -Credential $cred");
powershell.AddScript(@"$a = Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {" + cmdlet + "}");
powershell.AddScript(@"Remove-PSSession -Session $s");
powershell.AddScript(@"echo $a");
```

Where Credential is the C# PSCredential object

Comment: Why don't you use C# instead of adding all the scripts? You don't need to create the session by yourself. Take a look at RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace and PowerShell.Runspace.

Comment: Hi d.g, can you please let me know what `powershell` is? Is that a RunSpace object?

Comment: What is the difference between ps.AddParameter and ps.AddArgument?